# "by validating" - missing direct object?

Tags: direct-objects

According to several dictionaries I have, "validate" is a transitive verb. But both Grammarly and ChatGPT judge the following (imperative) sentence as correct:

*Ensure feature quality by validating with the UI team before release.*

I would use:
*Ensure feature quality by validating **it** with the UI team before release.*

Is the sentence without *it* correct? If yes, is it because the verb can be intransitive or because of something else?

Edit: corrected *them* to *it*.

Comment: You're allowed to omit the object of a transitive verb if it's obvious from context. Especially in contexts like "Ensure feature quality by validating with the UI team before release" which might not even be a sentence - it could be an imperative but is as likely to be something written in note form with the subject omitted. And with verbal nouns like "validating".

Comment: Here we have techie talk that shortens phrasing religiously.

Comment: I like running, jumping, fishing, and validating.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Those _ing_ forms are ambiguous between a verb and a noun, though verb preferred ("I like to run/fish"). "Validating" is questionable.